# I want a color ramp to be applied to an object along the axis of a spotlight. How would I set this up?

Tags: lighting, vector-mapping

More detail: I want the ramp aligned with the spot light so that the beginning of the ramp is where the light first hits the object and the end of the ramp is the farthest point from the light. I tried using Texture Coordinate (set to object) and Mapping nodes for tweaking, but I can't see how to align it. Can you help me?

Cheers,

Comment: and u wanna do that in shader nodes? geonodes? animation nodes? maybe you "forgot" to tag shader-nodes?

Comment: Do you need to automate the distances marked by the arrows? ..https://imgur.com/a/kpwyfut